# How To Set Azure Container Instance Restart Policy With .Net Fluent SDK

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-container-instances

How do I configure the restart policy when creating an Azure Container Instance using the .Net Fluent Management SDK? Am I missing something obvious or has is the SDK lagging behind the feature?

```
                _azure.ContainerGroups.Define(containerGroupName)
                    .WithRegion(Region.USEast)
                    .WithExistingResourceGroup("my-resource-group")
                    .WithLinux()
                    .WithPrivateImageRegistry("myreg.azurecr.io", "registry", "XXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                    .WithoutVolume()
                    .DefineContainerInstance(containerGroupName)
                        .WithImage("my-image/tag")
                        .WithoutPorts()
                        .WithCpuCoreCount(4)
                        .WithMemorySizeInGB(0.5)
                        .WithEnvironmentVariable("containerGroup", containerGroupName)
                        .Attach()
                    .Create();
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

> How do I configure the restart policy when creating an Azure Container Instance using the .Net Fluent Management SDK?

According to the Fluent SDK I find that we could set restart policy with following code

```
containerGroup.Inner.RestartPolicy = ContainerRestartPolicy.Always;
```

**Demo code:**

```
var containerGroup = _azure.ContainerGroups.Define(containerGroupName)
                .WithRegion(Region.USEast)
                .WithExistingResourceGroup("my-resource-group")
                .WithLinux()
                .WithPrivateImageRegistry("myreg.azurecr.io", "registry", "XXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                .WithoutVolume()
                .DefineContainerInstance(containerGroupName)
                .WithImage("my-image/tag")
                .WithoutPorts()
                .WithCpuCoreCount(4)
                .WithMemorySizeInGB(0.5)
                .WithEnvironmentVariable("containerGroup", containerGroupName)
                .Attach()
                .Create();

 containerGroup.Inner.RestartPolicy = ContainerRestartPolicy.Always;
```

**Note:** I find that the ContainerRestartPolicy just has one default value **always**, I don't test it on my side. I am not sure whether other value **Never and OnFailure** work

If **[ContainerInstanceManagementClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent/)** is possible, we could create Azure Container Instance with ContainerInstanceManagementClient

```
ContainerInstanceManagementClient client = new ContainerInstanceManagementClient(new TokenCredentials(token));

  var containerGroup = new ContainerGroupInner
            {
                Location = "xx",
                Containers = new List<Container>(),
                ImageRegistryCredentials = new List<ImageRegistryCredential>(),
                RestartPolicy = "xxx"

            };

var groupInner = client.ContainerGroups.CreateOrUpdateAsync("resourceGroup", "containerGroupName", containerGroupInner).Result;
```

Comment: In your first solution, does that get sent to Azure just by setting the property?

Comment: You are correct the default restartProperty is "Always". You can reference the ACI API which denotes the options for restartPolicy to include "Never" and "OnFailure" here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/containergroups/createorupdate#containergrouprestartpolicy

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-restart-policy#specify-a-restart-policy), set restart policy when you are starting up the container. 
In my example below, I set the policy to "Never", **.WithRestartPolicy(ContainerGroupRestartPolicy.Never)**

```
_azure.ContainerGroups.Define(containerGroupName)
                    .WithRegion(Region.USEast)
                    .WithExistingResourceGroup("my-resource-group")
                    .WithLinux()
                    .WithPrivateImageRegistry("myreg.azurecr.io", "registry", "XXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                    .WithoutVolume()
                    .DefineContainerInstance(containerGroupName)
                        .WithImage("my-image/tag")
                        .WithoutPorts()
                        .WithCpuCoreCount(4)
                        .WithMemorySizeInGB(0.5)
                        .WithEnvironmentVariable("containerGroup", containerGroupName)
                .WithRestartPolicy(ContainerGroupRestartPolicy.Never)

                        .Attach()
                    .Create();
```

From the docs:

> How you specify a restart policy depends on how you create your
>   container instances, such as with the Azure CLI, Azure PowerShell
>   cmdlets, or in the Azure portal. In the Azure CLI, specify the
>   --restart-policy parameter when you call az container create.